# How to suggest auto-complete in forwardRef by typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to access auto-complete for `forwardRef` via `useImperativeHandle`, but typescript cannot infer its methods (e.g. foo, bar, log)

```
import * as React from 'react'

const Re = React.forwardRef((_, ref) => {
    React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        log: console.log,
        foo: () => 5,
        bar: (num: number) => num + 2
    }), [])
    return null
})



const App = () => {
    const ref = React.createRef()
   
    //  Why we don't have any suggestion here for ref.current
    // ref.current?
    return <Re ref={ref} />

}
```

**Typescript Playground**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript can only infer types based on things that it already knows.  It won't make inferences based on things which happen later on in your code.

The type for the `ref` variable is assigned at the point where you create it by calling `React.createRef()`.  Typescript does not know at this point that you intend to pass that ref to the `Re` component.  So the ref type is `unknown`.

You must tell Typescript what type you want the `ref` to be at the point where you create it.  You do this by setting the generic on `React.createRef()` (or `React.useRef()`).

```
import * as React from "react";

interface MyRef {
  log: typeof console.log;
  foo: () => number;
  bar: (num: number) => number;
}

const Re = React.forwardRef<MyRef, any>((_, ref) => {
  React.useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
      log: console.log,
      foo: () => 5,
      bar: (num: number) => num + 2
    }),
    []
  );
  return null;
});

const App = () => {
  const ref = React.createRef<MyRef>();

  const someFunc = () => {
    // ref.current is null | MyRef
    if (ref.current) {
      // ref.current is MyRef
      ref.current.log("hello world");
      ref.current.log(ref.current.bar(9));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={someFunc}>Execute</button>
      <Re ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Clicking the "Execute" button in that code calls the functions from `Re` and logs `hello world` and `11`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, is there a way to shorthand declaration of API used in useImperativeHandler and MyRef interface. is there a way that interface can be generated base on that API ?